# Is this system invertible?

Tags: inverse, signal-processing

$y(t) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {x(t)^2}{x(t-1)} dt\\$
I was trying to prove or disprove the invertibility of this function. The only thing I could think of was differentiating it. But that does not solve the problem completely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Won't the right-hand side always be the same constant, the way that you have written it?

Comment: The denominator is time shifted.

Comment: @Pure Yes, but you are integrating with respect to $t$, so the integral evaluates to the same every time.

Comment: So that means it is not invertible? I'd appreciate it if you could write a complete answer. I would accept it as well. Thank you.

Comment: Did you really intend for the integrand to be a function of $t$ and the integral to be with respect to $t$? If so, then, knowing nothing about $x(t)$, it's impossible to determine even if the integral exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that as you integrate over $-\infty<t<\infty$, the right-hand side covers all possible values of $t$. So, the right-hand side will just be constant. Nowhere does changing the value of $t$ in the $y(t)$ on the left-hand side change anything. We could rewrite the equation as:
$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x(s)^2}{x(s-1)}ds$$ and it would mean the same thing. Therefore, $y$ is not invertible: it takes on the same value everywhere, so any attempt at an inverse would not be well-defined.

Comment: Note that this all relies on knowing enough about $x(t)$ to say that the integral exists.